# Duplication of record on insert in php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I notice sometimes that there are duplicated data when inserting in the database. It doesn't always happen but what might be the issue here? Here is my code.

```
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO registration(lrn, department_id, fname, mname, lname, contact_no, email, persontocontact, emergency_contact, agreement, statuss) VALUES('".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['departmentid']."', '".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['mname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['contact_no']."','".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['persontocontact']."', '".$_POST['emergency_contact']."', '".$_POST['agreement']."', 'pending')");

if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: we wouldn't be able to figure out why with that small piece of code you posted there. so we could only guess on our side. you're probably not checking whether it already exists, or you're not doing a simple post-redirect-get, and when the user refreshes the page, that's why it happens. p.s. you're vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Thank you. How to make not vulnerable to sql injection ?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: This code makes 1 insert unless it's executed several times. Is your page reloading? Or maybe preloading? How are you triggering this code? Post more details.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens sometimes means it is not the code that is doing it but the user actions like refresh on that page.

You should make it much more secure and handle the refresh situation but to answer to your question use this code.

```
$checkid = $_POST['userid'];//Specifically taking it here so you can know this is what we are looking for.
$sql = $conn->query("Select * from registration WHERE lrn = '$checkid'");


if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
   echo "User Already Exists";
}
else
{//Move forward
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO registration(lrn, department_id, fname, mname, lname, contact_no, email, persontocontact, emergency_contact, agreement, statuss) VALUES('".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['departmentid']."', '".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['mname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['contact_no']."','".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['persontocontact']."', '".$_POST['emergency_contact']."', '".$_POST['agreement']."', 'pending')");

if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
   echo "success";
}

}//Main if closes here
```

Comment: Ahh see. Thank you @Keral Patel.